# I don't have file of bower.json in visual 2017

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bower

I create a project with visual 2017 15.3 and core 2.1.I don't have bower.json to add bootstrap and ...when I try to add it by Manage bower packages I have an this error.
"An error occured installing "bootstrap". Would you like to open the output window to see the details?"
and
" EINVRES Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-validation failed with 502"
what do i do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybaMR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Open .bowerrc file located in the root folder of the project.
Add registry property to the file's content, pointing to the new bower registry. It should look like this:

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io",
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

Read this: Workaround for Bower Version Deprecation